# New Relic Custom Metrics - Cannot get it to work

Tags: .net, newrelic

I've tried to follow the New Relic documentation at https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/dotnet-agent-custom-metrics for setting up custom metrics on our web application but cannot get it to work.

In the New Relic trace we see lots of

> Application code (in System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest()) - Our agent can't see what is happening in your **.NET** code. Consult our documentation to find out how to add custom metrics to your app.

So, I've created a MyInstrumentation.xml file, put it in the extensions folder and am still not seeing any additional metrics. What am I doing wrong?

Here is example XML of my custom metrics:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension xmlns="urn:newrelic-extension">
<instrumentation>
  <tracerFactory>
    <match assemblyName="WebSite.Area" className="WebSite.Area.Controllers.MyController">
      <exactMethodMatcher methodName="MyMethod" />
    </match>
  </tracerFactory>
  <tracerFactory>
    <match assemblyName="Business.CustomerBL" className="Business.CustomerBL.MyBusinessClass">
      <exactMethodMatcher methodName="SaveCustomer" />
    </match>
  </tracerFactory>
</instrumentation>
</extension>
```

Comment: I've left it a day and I'm now seeing the data I was missing. Do I have to restart something to pick up my changes?

Comment: Yes, after adding the extension file for your custom metrics, you'll need to restart IIS. More specifically, an app pool recycle is necessary if the metrics you want to collect are for methods in an untrusted assembly (not in the GAC), and an IISReset is necessary if the metrics you want to collect are for methods in a trusted assembly (in the GAC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An application pool recycle was what was required