# New Relic - View App code

Tags: .net, newrelic

I'm exploring New Relic. 
I'm monitoring some applications I have on different servers.
When I am trying to figure out what actions cost me most time, I'm getting to the point I am seeing that I'm getting:

> Application code (in System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest()) - Our agent can't see what is happening in your .NET code. Consult our documentation to find out how to add custom metrics to your app.

So I found out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680249/new-relic-custom-metrics-cannot-get-it-to-work)

It means that I must write custom XML files for ALL the methods I have in all classes that I suspect??
Or there is something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the [New Relic thread profiler](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/applications-menu/events/thread-profiler-dashboard) to find some likely candidates for methods to instrument.

Comment: thanks, I will try to use this tool, i'll mark it answered if this tool will help me ;)